# What are advantages and disadvantages of raw files in SSIS and when do we use them?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, raw-file

Could anyone please describe the advantages and disadvantages of Raw file transformations in ssis packages and in which instances do we use them?

Answer (score 2):

*You can ask a your question in another way, **what is the difference between flat files and raw files in ssis***

A flat file is just any ordinary file with text in it: a .txt file, a .csv file and so on.  you can read them using a text editor. You must add a flat file connection manager to use them.

A raw file is essentially a dump of your data in SSIS to the file system. This is done in a proprietary binary format, so you can't read them yourself. This is used for quickly reading/writing data between different stages in the ETL. And there is No need to a connection manager to use them.

**You can read more in these links**

- [Flat Files vs RAW Files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad04db9b-bb02-4e4a-a79b-9f6fe3fe4622/flat-file-destination-vs-raw-file-destination-?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Raw Files performance](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2009/12/14/performance-of-raw-files-vs-flat-files/)